# How to test string for valid double content with boost::spirit::x3?

Tags: c++, validation, parsing, boost-spirit-x3

I am trying to determine if a given string is a valid double representation.
The code I am using looks like this:

```
bool testNumeric(const std::string& s)
{
    try
    {
        const auto doubleParser = boost::spirit::x3::double_;
        auto iter = s.begin();
        auto end_iter = s.end();
        double result = 0.;
        boost::spirit::x3::parse(iter, end_iter, doubleParser, result);
        return iter == end_iter;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am not interested in the resulting double (for now).
If I give this function an input of "1e10000000", which is obviously too large for double, the program fails with an assertion (BOOST_ASSERT). Can this somehow be changed to either fail by return code or throw an exception, which I can catch?
Or do I have to write my own double parser with spirit::x3?

Comment: Why not simply use [`std::stod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) or [`std::strtod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude certainly because these functions are not bothered with trailing non numeric chars after a valid numeric entry (e.g. if locale expects a dot and not a comma, the programme might understand 3 when user may type 3,1415 and nobody would notice the error since the data would be considered as correct.

Comment: You can use the `pos` argument to detect trailing characters

Comment: @Christophe Those functions support checking for that too. `std::stod` with the `pos` argument and `std::strtod` with the `str_end` argument.

Comment: I tested performance of std::strtod against boost::spirit::x3::double_ (micro-benchmark with nonius) and it takes about 50% longer to test with this one. Also it uses errno...
Will try std::from_chars next and post results here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I created a custom parsing method which first uses boost::spirit::x3::int_ on the exponent part of the double's string representation (if it exists) and returns if the exponent does not satisfy the bounds of the double type. Afterwards I call the boost::spirit::x3::double_ parser on valid strings.